# How to render evolving heightmap in Unity5?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I generate a grayscale heightmap in Unity, and I would like to render it. Similar to a terrain in Unity, but not using the terrain component and with the ability to change very often without too much performance loss.

Currently I generate a grid mesh (in c#) and then alter the vertexes each frame in a script. This, however, is slow, and limits the resolution of my heightmap (Unity only allows meshes up to 65000 vertices).

So I was wondering, is there a better way to render this heightmap?

Notes:

- The heightmap is changed almost every frame.
- I use one channel of my texture (currently the red one) to store the height.
- The resolution is a main problem, it should allow 512, 1024 and up.
- I'm working in Unity5 on mac.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'm pretty certain using a mesh instead of a heightmap is going to tank your performance regardless.

Comment: Yes. With 'as a mesh' I just meant that the geometry is actually moved. So not like a normal-map, faking it. I removed the 'as a mesh' part because it could indeed be misinterpreted.

Comment: Do you need the resulting geometry to be significant in the scene, or is it acceptable if it's visual-only? If the latter, a vertex shader might be able to handle that on the GPU.

Comment: For the moment visual-only is ok. However, it would later be part of a game. The height-map I generate is for a water and ground simulation, similar to From Dusk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do this a while ago, but forgot to post my solution. So here it is over a year later, maybe it'll help someone else:

You can simply add a vertex function into any shader:

First add something like: `#pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows vertex:vert` (the `vertex:vert` part is important, a similar line will probably already be in the shader, so just add that to that line).

Then create the vertex function with the name you have it ("vert" in my case):

```
void vert(inout appdata_full v) {
    float4 wsr = tex2Dlod(_MyTexture, v.texcoord);
    v.vertex.y = wsr.r + wsr.g + wsr.b;
}
```

You'll also need a sampler in there somewhere (I just put it above the vert function)

```
sampler2D _MyTexture;
```